# Can I use SpringBoardServices in my application which I want to submit in app store

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c

I want to use SpringBoardServices in my application, I am done with what I want to do with this framework, Now I want to submit the app on AppStore. Is it ok to use this framework in the app?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247052/how-to-use-springboard-services-framework-to-use-sbslaunchapplicationwithidentif

Answer (score 2):

I'm affraid not - because [SpringboardService framework](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/SpringBoardServices.framework) is a private one.

As a rule of thumb: if you can't find official Apple documentation for a certain framework it is considered to be private thus app using it would not be eligible to be published in the App Store.

Official reason for this is that private frameworks are not guranteed to be compatible over the iOS versions. And of course exposing a lot of them increases security risks and privacy issues - which sometimes sounds like a bad joke.

EDIT: by official Apple documentation I mean, well, official Apple documentation.

I usually google it with a query like:

```
SpringBoardService reference inurl:ios
```

Official Apple documentation would be located under domain `developer.apple.com`

There are (allegedly) some ways to camouflage private API calls in order to get your app trough the App Store revision process - but i would really advize against it.

Comment: Could you share any link to support your answer because I couldn't find any?

Comment: Clause 2.5 of the App Store guidelines - *"Apps that use non-public APIs will be rejected"*.

Comment: @rokjarc: your link is also showing that this is a private framework. Is there any way to use it in the app?

Comment: @rokjarc: I got this link http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PrivateFrameworks. I think I am wrong.

Comment: @rokjarc: as I got to know that it is really not a good idea to use private framework, can you give me a favor, how to get application information which is on the top of springboard?

Comment: As far as i know you can - without using private APIs - only get information about your application (from within your application) state

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @rokjarc's point that [SpringBoardServices.framework](https://github.com/nst/iOS-Runtime-Headers/tree/master/PrivateFrameworks/SpringBoardServices.framework) is a private framework. These frameworks are specifically labelled by word "Private" which means Apple don't want other people to use these. Private frameworks are intended to be used only by Apple's apps.

Reference:-1. http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki//System/Library/Frameworks#Private_Frameworks
 2. http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/PrivateFrameworks

Edited:- Check this answer if you really want to go for private framework:- [iOS Private Frameworks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9171160/ios-private-frameworks/9171286#9171286)

Comment: have you used any private api in any of your application, which is in the store?

Comment: Piyush is correct. @Akhiles: you can try to somehow sneak your private-API-using-app on the AppStore. But it will in best case work only on a certain percentage of the devices and most probably you will not be even able to get it trough the revision process.